# Button action controller

Tags: magento2, php

I tried to find where did a button send data to do something. For example, for a button below, it is a button on "Ship to Multiple Addresses" page.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter a New Address') ?>" class="action add" data-role="add-new-address">
   <span>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter a New Address') ?>
   </span>
</button>
```

So, where i can find the logic for that button? Is it in controller? or other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find newShipping button logic from below file,
Logic is reside in contorller file.

```
vendor/magento/module-multishipping/Controller/Checkout/Address/NewShipping.php
```

Go to execute function and you can find your logic as above file.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how could that button call that controller? Is it by class? or by data role?

Comment: By default button click form submit, you can check form action above button html and on form action they redirect to above action.

Comment: It is called getPostActionUrl(), and it is return $this->getUrl('*/*/addressesPost');
Is that mean its called controller with name "AddressesPost.php"?